# SQL: use calculated field or leave it to the software

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm modeling a stadium tickets database. I have a `TICKET`,`FAN`, `CARD`, `EVENT`, `SEAT` and `SECTOR` entities (and others). There are areound 40k seats, and 45 sectors. The price is calculated like this more or less:

1. The `EVENT` has a base price
2. The price changes depending on the `SECTOR`
3. Depending on the `FAN` age he could have an ulterior discount
4. The `FAN` has a `CARD` and depending on which type of card he could have a discount

`TICKET` is linked with a 1:1 to everything except `CARD` and `SECTOR` (but `SEAT` is weak towards `SECTOR` so he can see its key)

Should I calculate the price in my database? Only if I need to store it? If yes how should I do it, leave it as a calculated field in `TICKET`?

I hope I've been clear enough, thank for every answer 
EDIT: I don't want the sql code to calculate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider it a good idea to have that algorithm implemented in the database, such as to use the same algorithm and code from every app or webservice or whatever you intend to build some day.

I would create a stored procedure to calculate the price. You would call this procedure whenever you want a price calculated.

Once a ticket is issued, its price is fixed however, so you would usually store the price with the ticket. Later you may change discounts, so the same kind of ticket gets cheaper, but the one already sold doesn't of course. That said, use the stored procedure to calculate the ticket price initially. When issuing the ticket, store that current price with it.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted to know